# Table attribute width is ignored

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

My goal is to generate a html file with tables and export them into pdf.
Unfortunately I cant get the table to act like I want.

One part of the table should display a timescale with days on the lowest row, weeks,months and years are in the rows above and have a pre-calculated colspan.

Only the s for the days have a width given with CSS (`style="width:..."`).

The problem is that the width is totally ignored, so fields with days from 1-9 are only half as width than the others. And in follow, because the fields above size automatically because they have no width given, their size is also wrong.

[alt text http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/6617/scale1x.jpg](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/6617/scale1x.jpg)

Heres the source that is generated:
http://pastebin.com/JyiqhSzs

What we tried so far:

- used non css (`width=""`)
- give the other field also an calculated width (the colspan value multiplied with the width of a day)

Also set `style="table-layout:fixed;"` for the table but that has no effect.

So I don't know how to get the table to have the width I want to have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `width: 23px` use `min-width: 23px`. It worked for IE8 and FireFox. I have not yet figured out a magic formula for IE7 to not narrow the single digit days (working on it). I do know that the `table-layout: fixed` is not needed, and for sure will cause issues with any IE7 display that may work.

Also, if you always want them to be the same size, you might consider using `em` sizing so that if text size changes, your table scales up/down with it proportionally. I don't know all your needs, but just a suggestion to look into.

*Edit: More cross browser solution.* IE6 and 7 need to have all the numbers in the "days" cells wrapped with a `div` and then instead of styling the `td` with any kind of width, style that `div` with a `width: 23px` ***not*** `min-width: 23px`.

Comment: `min-width` worked for me too. It would be interesting to know *why* `width`does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Is the `style` attribute mistyped as `stlye` in your real page, too?

Some more hints:

- It's normal for table cell to shrink if the table doesn't fit on the whole page, that's how HTML tables work.
- Try `table-layout: fixed` after fixing the typo.
- If it still doesn't work you'll need to add a `div` (or some other element) to each cell and give that the width instead
- A width in pixels won't work if the font isn't the size you expect (and no, you can't force it to a specific size). Try `2ex`.
- Instead of setting the style in each and every `td` why don't you set in the the style sheet.

Example:

```
<tr class="days"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>

tr.days td {
  width: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just specify "width=...", you have to change the way the CSS element displays...

So lets assume we want the cell to be 30px wide:

```
style="width: 30px !important; display: block;"
```

display: block; basically tells the CSS that it must resize the element based on the dimensions given in width: and height: and not based on what's actually in the element.

However, there is a small concern with doing this that the contents of the element might stretch beyond the bounds specified by width and height, but in this type of situation, I don't think that's going to be a big issue.

HTH

Comment: It doesn't work for me. But I must say, that I have edited only the last rows or shall I edit all?

Comment: Apply the change to all the cells that are having problems, failing that, add padding: 0 2px 0 2px !important; to the style. This will place 2px extra space on the left and right of the cells.

Comment: Having downloaded your code from the pastebin and fiddling around, I see that adding padding won't work.
If you can change to colspan on the "bad" cells, that should do it, but  that might mean having to edit every single cell to get it to display right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue on a similar case by setting the width at the `<td>` level to something a bit larger than the expected text, like:

```
<td style="width:50em">
```